# Can Opera Speed Dial extensions communicate with regular extensions?

Tags: opera-extension

Is there a way for a speed dial extension to use some sort of communication mechanism to talk to an extension?

We have an extension that does mail checking, but it uses a pretty complex login process involving tokens and cookies. We don't have an RSS feed for our mail.

We'd like a way for the Speed Dial to ask the extension for new mail.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use messaging to make the speed dial JS communicate with the background process. It works the same as normal message works in chromium based extensions.

Check out:

1. http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/tut_message_passing.html
2. http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/tut_sd_extensions.html

Comment: Is there some way to add a speed dial component to an existing extension? Or does the speed dial always have to be a separate extension?